# Transform all elements of union type

Tags: typescript

BI'd like to modify each element in a union type. I haven't been able to find any way to achieve this.

---

#### Simple example

From this:

```js
type U = string | number
```

What I can do:

```js
type A = U[] // (string | number)[]
```

What I would like to be able to do:

```js
type B = ... // string[] | number[]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to *distribute* the `T` -> `Array<T>` type operation over unions in `T`.  You can use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to do this, by making sure `T` is a type parameter, and doing any conditional type check on it, like this:

```
type DistributeArrayOverUnions<T> = T extends any ? T[] : never;
type B = DistributeArrayOverUnions<U> // string[] | number[];
```

The `DistributeArrayOverUnions<T>` is pretty much just doing `T[]`, but by wrapping that in `T extends any ? ... : never`, we are distributing the operation across unions in `T`. And that distribution is the only purpose of that check; it's a no-op otherwise.

---

Note that you need to do that as a two-step process; since `U` is just a type and not a type *parameter*, the following will not work because it will not distribute:

```
type Bad = U extends any ? U[] : never; // type Bad = (string | number)[]
```

---

It is possible to collapse the two steps to a one-liner if you must, by using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to bring a new type parameter into scope, like this:

```
type C = U extends infer T ? T extends any ? T[] : never : never;
// string[] | number[];
```

But that is probably even uglier and harder to explain than the two-step process, so I'd stick with that if I were you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqlC8UDOwBOBLAdgcygHykwFcBbAIwlQG4AoG0SKAEXRQzKOAgEFVUBDEAHkAbpRiZ0Ae0xIAPABUAfAigKoEAB5dMAEyRR+mEFAD8agNoBdKAC5CEMdXrhoAIVUs26Dl14DhJwlpWTkYFQB6COQ0LGxrfEJSClRrWhdGN35dVTgtHX1DYzNYBPtMR0oqKCioBnds1QAKbxxE4nJKAEprOgzoAGFcjW0IPQMsADNKNRL1fLHCoxNzBTKHJzsNqppa1vibAg6UtJogA)